# How to set a static variable in every class?

Tags: eclipse, aspectj

I am trying to do something very simple. I have a com.mypackage.Logger logger class whose instantiation statement I would like to "insert" into every single class like so: `private static Logger LOG = new Logger(Class.class)`. Then, I would like to log every single entry and exit instance for every single function in my project. Here is my aspect:

```
public aspect LoggingAspect pertypewithin(*) {

   private static Logger LOG;

   pointcut classes(): within(com.mypackage..*) && !within(com.mypackage.Logger) && !within(com.mypackage.LoggingAspect);
   pointcut functions(): classes() && (execution(* *(..)) || execution(new(..)));

   before(): staticinitialization(*) && classes() {
      LOG = new Logger(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature().getDeclaringType());
   }

   before() : functions() {
      LOG.trace("ENTER " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toLongString());
   }


   after() returning(@SuppressWarnings("unused") Object ret) : functions() {
      LOG.trace("EXIT " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().toLongString());
   }
```

Almost everything works properly. I am getting correct enter and exist log statements exactly as expected. The problem is that the logging class that is associated with each log entry is incorrect. I am using log4j, and each log entry is formatted like so:

[TRACE] (date and time stamp) (logging class name) (thread name) (some logging statement)

**The problem is that the logging class used in Logger instantiation does not match the correct one that is indicated by `thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getDeclaringTypeName()`.**

I know that I am not doing something right with respect to the static Logger variable, so please help me. thank you for your time!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple

Your LOG attribute is defined as private **static**. Static means that's a **class attribute**, not instance attribute.

This is clearly contradicting the **instanciation model** of your aspect, which is *pertypewithin* (one instance of aspect created for each type).

Try to remove the **static** modifier.

By the way, defining *pertypewithin(*)* is quite large, you can restrict down the matching with *pertypewithin(classes())*

For the logging stuff, I've done some experimentations with AspectJ using instanciation model & inter-type declarations. I would advise the implementation using inter-type declaration because it is more memory-saving:

[Logger injection with perthis](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/advanced-aspectj-part-i-instanciation-model/)

[Logger injection with inter-type declaration](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/advanced-aspectj-part-ii-inter-type-declaration/)